# MediaPipe Face Landmarks has a x-axis offset

Tags: android-studio, mediapipe, facial-landmark-alignment, face-landmark

I'm new to mediapipe, and I used its Face Landmarks on my app, but i has an offset for all the points. as you can see, all the points have the same x offset.
[landmarks preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VUFM.jpg)

I tried to implement it on overlay class(I checked my xml files, and It was the same with the orginal app which did not has this offset first) in various valuse:

```
   for (landmark in faceLandmarkerResult.faceLandmarks()) {
            for (normalizedLandmark in landmark) {
                // Apply the X offset to the X coordinate
                val adjustedX = (normalizedLandmark.x() * imageWidth * scaleFactor) - xOffset
                val adjustedY = normalizedLandmark.y() * imageHeight * scaleFactor
                canvas.drawPoint(adjustedX, adjustedY, pointPaint)
            }
        }
```

but still nothing has been changed. could you please guide me in the case of removing this offset? I'm showing landmarks on a fragment:

```
class DrowsinessFragment : Fragment(), FaceLandmarkerHelper.LandmarkerListener {
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "Face Landmarker"
    }
    val xOffset = -20f
    private var _fragmentCameraBinding: FragmentDrowsinessBinding? = null

    private val fragmentCameraBinding
        get() = _fragmentCameraBinding!!

    private lateinit var faceLandmarkerHelper: FaceLandmarkerHelper
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private val faceBlendshapesResultAdapter by lazy {
        FaceBlendshapesResultAdapter()
    }

    private var preview: Preview? = null
    private var imageAnalyzer: ImageAnalysis? = null
    private var camera: Camera? = null
    private var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider? = null
    private var cameraFacing = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT

    /** Blocking ML operations are performed using this executor */
    private lateinit var backgroundExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        // Make sure that all permissions are still present, since the
        // user could have removed them while the app was in paused state.


        // Start the FaceLandmarkerHelper again when users come back
        // to the foreground.
        backgroundExecutor.execute {
            if (faceLandmarkerHelper.isClose()) {
                faceLandmarkerHelper.setupFaceLandmarker()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if(this::faceLandmarkerHelper.isInitialized) {
            viewModel.setMaxFaces(faceLandmarkerHelper.maxNumFaces)
            viewModel.setMinFaceDetectionConfidence(faceLandmarkerHelper.minFaceDetectionConfidence)
            viewModel.setMinFaceTrackingConfidence(faceLandmarkerHelper.minFaceTrackingConfidence)
            viewModel.setMinFacePresenceConfidence(faceLandmarkerHelper.minFacePresenceConfidence)
            viewModel.setDelegate(faceLandmarkerHelper.currentDelegate)

            // Close the FaceLandmarkerHelper and release resources
            backgroundExecutor.execute { faceLandmarkerHelper.clearFaceLandmarker() }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        _fragmentCameraBinding = null
        super.onDestroyView()

        // Shut down our background executor
        backgroundExecutor.shutdown()
        backgroundExecutor.awaitTermination(
            Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS
        )
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _fragmentCameraBinding =
            FragmentDrowsinessBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return fragmentCameraBinding.root
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Initialize our background executor
        backgroundExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

        // Wait for the views to be properly laid out
        fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.post {
            // Set up the camera and its use cases
            setUpCamera()
        }

        // Create the FaceLandmarkerHelper that will handle the inference
        backgroundExecutor.execute {
            faceLandmarkerHelper = FaceLandmarkerHelper(
                context = requireContext(),
                runningMode = RunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,
                minFaceDetectionConfidence = viewModel.currentMinFaceDetectionConfidence,
                minFaceTrackingConfidence = viewModel.currentMinFaceTrackingConfidence,
                minFacePresenceConfidence = viewModel.currentMinFacePresenceConfidence,
                maxNumFaces = viewModel.currentMaxFaces,
                currentDelegate = viewModel.currentDelegate,
                faceLandmarkerHelperListener = this
            )
        }

        // Attach listeners to UI control widgets
//        initBottomSheetControls()
    }
    
    // Initialize CameraX, and prepare to bind the camera use cases
    private fun setUpCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture =
            ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(
            {
                // CameraProvider
                cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

                // Build and bind the camera use cases
                bindCameraUseCases()
            }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext())
        )
    }

    // Declare and bind preview, capture and analysis use cases
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    private fun bindCameraUseCases() {

        // CameraProvider
        val cameraProvider = cameraProvider
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("Camera initialization failed.")

        val cameraSelector =
            CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(cameraFacing).build()

        // Preview. Only using the 4:3 ratio because this is the closest to our models
        preview = Preview.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
            .setTargetRotation(fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.display.rotation)
            .build()

        // ImageAnalysis. Using RGBA 8888 to match how our models work
        imageAnalyzer =
            ImageAnalysis.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
                .setTargetRotation(fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.display.rotation)
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
                .build()
                // The analyzer can then be assigned to the instance
                .also {
                    it.setAnalyzer(backgroundExecutor) { image ->
                        detectFace(image)
                    }
                }

        // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()

        try {
            // A variable number of use-cases can be passed here -
            // camera provides access to CameraControl & CameraInfo
            camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalyzer
            )

            // Attach the viewfinder's surface provider to preview use case
            preview?.setSurfaceProvider(fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }
    }

    private fun detectFace(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        faceLandmarkerHelper.detectLiveStream(
            imageProxy = imageProxy,
            isFrontCamera = cameraFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
        )
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        imageAnalyzer?.targetRotation =
            fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.display.rotation
    }

    // Update UI after face have been detected. Extracts original
    // image height/width to scale and place the landmarks properly through
    // OverlayView

    override fun onResults(
        resultBundle: FaceLandmarkerHelper.ResultBundle
    ) {
        activity?.runOnUiThread {


                // Pass necessary information to OverlayView for drawing on the canvas
                fragmentCameraBinding.overlay.setResults(
                    resultBundle.result,
                    resultBundle.inputImageHeight,
                    resultBundle.inputImageWidth,
                    RunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,
                    xOffset // Pass the X offset
                )
                // Force a redraw
                fragmentCameraBinding.overlay.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onEmpty() {
        fragmentCameraBinding.overlay.clear()
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            faceBlendshapesResultAdapter.updateResults(null)
            faceBlendshapesResultAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    override fun onError(error: String, errorCode: Int) {
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            faceBlendshapesResultAdapter.updateResults(null)
            faceBlendshapesResultAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
//

        }
    }
}
```